# Magento 2 : How to hide add product button from admin panel

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, products, admin-panel, custom-admin-grid

How I can hide add product button from admin panel?

see image below for more clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am also not so sure but you can override Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product.php file 
by giving  in di.xml and can use `$this->buttonList->remove('add_new');` in `_prepareLayout` function.

**Note:** You can not use plugin as it is not public function.

Comment: This solution worked! Thanks

Comment: @FaisalSheikh pls vote, thanks!!!

Comment: Can you give me a complete answer